# How to build a buffer around the upper half of an ellipsoid?

Tags: r, buffer, rgl

What I´m looking for is a way to create an ellipsoid which is bigger than the one plotted in the example. So the ellipsoid should be like a buffer with a specific width of the plotted one.

Furthermore I´d like to "cut off" the upper part of the ellipsoid.

Any idea how to do that?

example taken from: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/a-complete-guide-to-3d-visualization-device-system-in-r-r-software-and-data-visualization

```
library("rgl")

data(iris)
head(iris)

x <- sep.l <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- pet.l <- iris$Petal.Length
z <- sep.w <- iris$Sepal.Width


rgl_init()
plot3d(x, y, z, col="blue", box = FALSE,
       type ="s", radius = 0.15)
ellips <- ellipse3d(cov(cbind(x,y,z)), 
                    centre=c(mean(x), mean(y), mean(z)), level = 0.99)
plot3d(ellips, col = "blue", alpha = 0.2, add = TRUE, box = FALSE)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how big you want to make the ellipsoid, but the `t` or `level` arguments to `ellipse3d()` both affect the size.  For cutting off part of it, you could try `clipplanes3d()`.

Comment: the size of the ellipsoid should be bigger than the limit of the level argument `(level = 0.99)`. So to use the `level` argument is no solution. The `t` argument I don´t understand completely. What I´m looking for is way to build a 3d buffer. `clipplanes3d()` allows to cut the points but not the ellipsoid.

Comment: `clipplanes3d()` applies to everything in the same "subscene".